# Speech act prediction data sets

Tags: data-request, nlp

I am looking for data sets containing dialogues labeled with [speech acts](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/speech-acts/). I am open as to the definition of a dialogue, e.g. message board posts are good too (1).

Example (`FOL`, `QST`, and `RES` are speech act categories; `opening`, `info`, `confirm`, `positive` are speech act attributes):

```
(G) Hi, good afternoon. 0000    FOL(opening)
(T) Hi, good afternoon. 0001    FOL(opening)
(G) %Uh this is tour guide %uh number one And my name is Lynnette.  0002    FOL(opening); FOL(info-opening)
(G) And how do I address you?   0003    QST(opening)
(T) I'm %uh participant number twenty and my name is %uh John.  0004    FOL(info)
(G) John?   0005    QST(confirm-opening)
(G) Hi John.    0006    FOL(opening)
(T) Yup.    0007    RES(confirm)
(T) I'm good.   0008    FOL(opening-positive)
```

---

(1) Qadir, Ashequl, and Ellen Riloff. "[Classifying sentences as speech acts in message board posts.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=13929144476142779063&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)" Proceedings of the Conference on Empirical Methods in Natural Language Processing. Association for Computational Linguistics, 2011.